# Could a kilometer of sand as wide as the runway,1 meter deep stop an Airbus A380 if it overshot the runway

Tags: safety, airbus-a380, runway-overrun

An aircraft overshooting the runway could prove to be fatal.  Assuming an Airbus A380 is fully loaded at near take off speed and pilots decide its would be best to abort take off, if they slammed the brakes and they were not as efficient and they approached 1000m of sand as wide as the runway one meter or more deep placed at the end of the runway for safety in likelihood of such incidents, traveling at near take off speed.  Would the sand be able to stop the aircraft?

For the purposes of this question we'll assume the sand is either:

A. Desert sand as fund in the UAE -or-
B. Riversand

Comment: Thats what [EMAS is for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineered_materials_arrestor_system)...

Comment: Related: [How does EMAS reduce damage in case of an aircraft overrun?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32750/14897)